# Unable to upgrade/downgrade android subscription using in_app_purchase flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase

I am fetching past purchase details and as mentioned in the documentation I am providing the fetched details to `ChangeSubscriptionParam` with required `ProationMode`.

However I am getting error in playstore modal as `Something went wrong on our end. Please try again`, and the debug console says `Activity finished with resultCode 0 and billing's responseCode: 5`.

This is the code I am using :

```
final platform = iapConnection
            .getPlatformAddition<InAppPurchaseAndroidPlatformAddition>();
        final pastPurchases = await platform.queryPastPurchases();

        GooglePlayPurchaseDetails? oldPurchaseDetails;

        // Assumes 1 or none active purchase.
        for (var purchase in pastPurchases.pastPurchases) {
          oldPurchaseDetails = purchase;
        }

        final purchaseParam = GooglePlayPurchaseParam(
            productDetails: event.productDetails,
            changeSubscriptionParam: oldPurchaseDetails != null
                ? ChangeSubscriptionParam(
                    oldPurchaseDetails: oldPurchaseDetails,
                    prorationMode: ProrationMode.deferred)
                : null);

        await iapConnection.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason for my error. So I was trying subscription model in India and had 3 subscription model set up however 2 of them were priced above 5000 because of which they were being treated as prepaid plan ([India's Subscription Rules](https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/engineering/indias-new-subscription-rules/#:%7E:text=back%20in%20May.-,Auto%2Drenewing%20subscription%20products%20will%20be%20capped%20below%205%2C000%20INR,are%20priced%20under%205%2C000%20INR)). And according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#change) When upgrading, downgrading to a prepaid plan from auto-renewing plan, the only allowed proration mode is IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_FULL_PRICE and I was aiming for DEFERED proration mode, hence the error.